# Replace string after last dot in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, string

I have the following pattern in a string (an IP address):

```
123.444.888.235
```

I want to replace the last number after the dot with `0`, so it becomes:

```
123.444.888.0
```

How could I do it in `bash` or another shell script language?

Comment: Where are those strings? In a bash variable? In a text file one per line?

Comment: It is in a variable. I am sorry was forgot to mention it.

Comment: If those are IP addresses, then 444 and 888 are invalid octet values.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In any POSIX shell:

```
var=123.444.888.235
new_var="${var%.*}.0"
```

`${var%pattern}` is an operator introduced by `ksh` in the 80s, standardized by POSIX for the standard `sh` language and now implemented by all shells that interpret that language, including `bash`.

`${var%pattern}` expands to the content of `$var` stripped of the shortest string that matches *pattern* off the end of it (or to the same as `$var` if that *pattern* doesn't match). So `${var%.*}` (where `.*` is a *pattern* that means dot followed by any number of characters) expands to `$var` without the right-most `.` and what follows it. By contrast, `${var%%.*}` where the *longest* string that matches the pattern is stripped would expand to `$var` without the left-most `.` and what follows it.

Comment: What is ***`${var%.*}`*** *?*

Comment: @tjt263, at the command line type `man bash` and press enter, then type `/suffix pattern` and press enter.  :)

Comment: Added some quotes [following your post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171347/79743):  `new_var="${var%.*}.0"` ... nJoy!.

Answer (score 9):

This should work.

```
echo 123.444.888.235 | sed 's/\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.\)[0-9]*/\10/'
```

Note that the last field of `sed` substitution, `\10`, is the first matched pattern (`\1`), concatenated with a literal zero.

Answer (score 6):

## General case for applying a netmask to an IP address:

Given that your input is an IP address, and that you are replacing the last octet of that address with `.0`, then I assume what you are *really* trying to achieve is to compute the network portion of the IP address, using the `255.255.255.0` netmask.

Simply replacing octets with zeroes is OK if your netmask length is divisible by 8, but this is not the general case.  If you ever need to perform this operation for any valid (subnet) netmask, then you can do something like this:

```bash
function d2i() {
    echo $(( 0x$( printf "%02x" ${1//./ } ) ))
}

function i2d() {
    h=$( printf "%08X" "$1" )
    echo $(( 0x${h:0:2} )).$(( 0x${h:2:2} )).$(( 0x${h:4:2} )).$(( 0x${h:6:2} ))
}

function ipmask() {
    i2d $(( $( d2i $1 ) & $( d2i $2 ) ))
}

ipmask 123.44.88.235 255.255.255.0     # outputs 123.44.88.0
ipmask 123.44.88.235 255.255.255.240   # outputs 123.44.88.224
```

This defines 3 functions:

- `d2i()` converts the dotted-decimal form of an IP address (or mask) to a simple integer
- `i2d()` does the opposite - converts a simple integer to a dotted decimal
- `ipmask()` simply computes a bitwise AND of an address and a netmask to give the network portion of an address.  Bash expects the operands of `&` to be integers.

The two calls to `ipmask` show how the network may be calculated from an IP address for two different masks.

---

Note as stated in the question, *`123.444.888.235`* is an invalid IP address.  I have used `123.44.88.235` instead for these examples.

Comment: Great answer!!!

Answer (score 5):

A few ways (these all assume that you want to change the last set of numbers in the string):

```
$ echo 123.444.888.235 | awk -F'.' -vOFS='.' '{$NF=0}1;'
123.444.888.0
```

Here, `-F'.'` tells `awk` to use `.` as the input field separator and `-vOFS='.'` to use it as the output field separator. Then, we simply set the last field (`$NF`) to 0 and print the line (`1;` is `awk` shorthand for "print the current line").

```
$ echo 123.444.888.235 | perl -pe 's/\d+$/0/'
123.444.888.0
```

The `-p` tells `perl` to print each input line after applying the script given by `-e`. The script itself is just a simple substitution operator which will replace one or more numbers at the end of the line with `0`.

```
$ echo 123.444.888.235 | sed 's/[0-9]*$/0/'
123.444.888.0
```

The same idea in `sed`, using `[0-9]` instead of `\d`.

---

If your string is in a variable and you use a shell that supports [here strings](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) (such as `bash` or `zsh` for example), you can change the above to:

```
awk -F'.' -vOFS='.' '{$NF=0}1;' <<<$var
perl -pe 's/\d+$/0/' <<<$var
sed 's/[0-9]*$/0/' <<<$var
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative `sed` answer :

```
sed -r 's/(.*\.).*/\10/'
```

It groups everything up to the last dot and replaces the full line with the content of the group followed by 0.
I use -r to avoid having to escape parentheses.